# Markers on the Line

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, google-maps-markers, pylons

I have a list of lists consisting of two different data for plotting 2 lines and another list of lists consisting of markers on these respective lines. but the list of list of markers can have empty set. I have written a code but it is not displaying any image. Can anyone tell me why the following few lines don't work?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Draw(Narratives, Prob_failure):        
    x=list(range(0,len(Narratives[0])))
    for i in range(len(Narratives)):
        plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
        if not Prob_failure[i]:
            plt.plot(x,Narratives[i])
        else:
            Int_Prob_failures = [int(x) for x in Prob_failure[i] ]
            markers_on = Int_Prob_failures
            plt.plot(x,Narratives[i],'-gD', markevery=markers_on)
    plt.xlim(0,len(Narratives[0]))
    plt.ylim(0.0, 2000.0)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xlabel('Length of the Data Narrative', fontsize=15)
    plt.ylabel('Intervals', fontsize=15)
    plt.title('Plotting Data Narratives', weight='bold')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

Data = [[40.495959999999997, 68.728006916094003, 80.991919999999993, 121.48787999999999, 161.98383999999999, 200.75514611468412, 202.47979999999998, 208.8702579527606, 242.97575999999998, 426.66599412223769, 598.13431735234519, 947.40769717700846], [40.495959999999997, 80.991919999999993, 121.48787999999999, 161.98383999999999, 202.47979999999998, 209.4165446035731, 242.97575999999998, 383.51736697098818, 451.56755438353258, 503.98594436505164, 516.26217431475163, 1099.3652534435903]]
Failures = [[68.728006916094003], []]
Draw(Data,Failures)
```

Comment: Could you adjust your code witht he right indentation...as it is now it is hard to read it

Comment: @astrom, oops sorry. I didn't notice. Please hang on

Comment: @Astrom, done! thanks

Comment: Do you have any error displayed?

Comment: @Astrom, nope. all it says is <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xec87d68>
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xe779b70>

Comment: are you supposed to have 2 figures?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141832/discussion-between-astrom-and-eric-enkele).

Comment: @Astrom, nope. I want to plot them both on the same figure.

Comment: ok so you should first put ` plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))` before the for loop, here you are creating a new plot in each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
Int_Prob_failures = [int(x) for x in Prob_failure[i] ]
markers_on = Int_Prob_failures
plt.plot(x,Narratives[i],'-gD', markevery=markers_on)
```

you can try with:

```
index = []
for j in range(len(Prob_failure[i])):
    for k in range(len(Narratives[i])):
        if Prob_failure[i][j] == Narratives[i][k]:
            index.append(k)
plt.plot(x,Narratives[i],'-gD', markevery = index )
```

the markevery option takes the *index* of the point you want to emphasis.